# How to add animations to windows forms elements?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, animation, user-experience

Coming from Silverlight environment, creating animated panels is painfully easy - I just put all my controls on a canvas, and added the following lines in XAML

```
            <Storyboard x:Name="canvasRight" 
                        Completed="canvasRight_Completed">
                <DoubleAnimation From="0" To="500" 
                                 Duration="0:0:0.6" 
                                 Storyboard.TargetName="aboutCanvas" 
                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Left)">

                    <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                        <QuinticEase EasingMode="EaseIn"/>
                    </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>

                </DoubleAnimation>
            </Storyboard>
```

Now whenever the user clicked on a "About" button somewhere, the canvas with some images and links to my webpage just nicely slid out from the right. Now obviously I know this isn't that easy when doing a Forms application, but I fail to see any way to do it at all. From what I've gathered the canvas equivalent is a Panel, on which I've put some controls. I can make the panel visible or invisible, but I would like to add the same kind of "slide out" effect to it. Is there any way to do so?

Comment: winforms are not meant to be offering animations, to apply animations WPF was introduced

Comment: Rather there are third party API`s for transitions. i dont remember exactly but search for transition.dll.

Comment: Animations in Windows Forms are simple. You do not need WPF for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have used this APi, its simple and complete documentations is available at 
http://code.google.com/p/dot-net-transitions/wiki/CodingWithTransitions

Answer (score 3):

Animations won't work well in WinForms.  Different technology.

You can try the [AnimateWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632669%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)  api to get close.

From [pinvoke.net](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/AnimateWindow.html):

```
[DllImport("user32")]
static extern bool AnimateWindow(IntPtr hwnd, 
                                 int time,
                                 AnimateWindowFlags flags);
```